# Regular expression not returning first number from 3 lines

Tags: regex, perl

Hi I am new with Perl programming, I wrote a code to store a first number from a scalar variable using regular expression but i am getting first number from last line but I need number from first line.

For example in the following code I need `$num = 22` but code returns `656`.

```
my $num ;

my $sample = "fd 22 sdf sdf 96 
dsf6 66s sd6 7777 sd
656 dd 55  ";

my @sentences = split(/\n/, $sample);


for my $line(@sentences)
{
    ($num )= $line =~ /([0-9]+) .*/ ;

    }
print $num;
```

Can some one tell me whats wrong with my logic?

Comment: You're overwriting the variable each time through the loop.

Comment: Why are you looping if you only care about the first line?

Comment: this is only test case but in my actual scenario I want to get the number from email subject therefore the subject can contain more than one line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code overwrites the first match in the following iterations of the loop, 22 matches but 666 replaces it. Just break after the first match:

```
($num )= $line =~ /([0-9]+) .*/ and last;
```

or remove the loop and match against the `sample`:

```
($num )= $sample =~ /([0-9]+)/;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the pattern as written won't filter out entries like "s67" in the following

my $sample = "fd 66s s67 22 sdf sdf 96
dsf6 66s 656 dd 55 ";

and so it needs something like

($num) = $line =~ /\b([0-9]+)\b.*/ and last;

Answer (score 0):

Or try

```
 ($num) = $sample =~ /[0-9]+/g
```